# How do we write years before AD 1000?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, dates

For years with 4 digits, usually we write it this way:

> George was born in the year 1732.
>
> or
>
> George was born in 1732.

What about years with three, two, or even one digit?

Are these examples still valid?

1. George was born in the year 732.
2. George was born in 732.
3. George was born in the year 32.
4. George was born in 32.
5. George was born in the year 2.
6. George was born in 2.

Comment: [The decline, seen in retrospect, occurred over a period of four centuries, culminating in the final dissolution of the Western Roman Empire on September 4, 476, when Romulus Augustus, the last Emperor of the Western Roman Empire, was deposed by Odoacer, a Germanic chieftain.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decline_of_the_Roman_Empire)

Comment: [Augustus died in 14 AD at the age of 75.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus)

Comment: [It was not until AD 8 that a food crisis of this sort prompted Augustus to establish a *praefectus annonae*, a permanent prefect who was in charge of procuring food supplies for Rome.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All your examples are all acceptable: it is not normal practice to use leading zeros.

I would, however, suggest prefixing (or suffixing) **all** of them with ***AD*** before (or after) the digits (especially so where you omit "the year"). I believe (but have not confirmed) that it is conventional to include "AD" for years of less than 4 digits (unless it is obvious from the context what era you are discussing), and the presence of "AD" helps to indicate that you have not unintentionally omitted a digit from the year.  It also, incidentally, clarifies (i) which calendar system you are using, and (ii) that you do not mean ***BC***.

Comment: Really?  You find *"George was born in 2."* acceptable?  Even though it's obvious from context that it's a year, it seems off to me.

Comment: @snailboat: Only if there is zero chance of ambiguity, but then, yes. With 2, that is unlikely, however. We normally write "Augustus died in the year 14" or "the year 14 AD", or "14 AD", but, if lots of years around that time have been mentioned in close proximity, I would find just "14" acceptable, mainly if you have, say, 5 different years in one sentence (otherwise it gets crowded). *Xanthus arrived in Italy in 2 AD, left again in 4, and married in Greece in the year 6.* I would find that acceptable.

Comment: AD and BC are now deprecated in academic contexts, and CE (Common Era) and BCE (Before the Common Era) are preferred. *George was born in 2 CE* (or *CE 2*).

Comment: @StoneyB: They have been deprecated for 50 years, but people tend to use BC/AD aynway. BCE/ACE are still rare.

Comment: All of those examples would be made substantially better by adding AD or BC, especially the lower numbers.

Comment: @StoneyB (1) The OP introduced the *AD* terminology (in the subject/title). (2) In the UK, *CE* (also C.of E.) is a common abbreviation for *Church of England*. If I saw *CE* against a date, I would be wondering what it had to do with the Church of England!

Comment: @TrevorD That's what I thought the first fifteen or twenty times I saw it. But against political correctness the gods themselves struggle in vain.